# Qt generate UI based on template

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm looking to generate a set of labels and buttons based on some kind of template, but I don't know how to do the template part.

I'll be using a tab widget which I already have set up, and in one the tabs, I want to have a two labels, a custom button, and a textbox. It'll be repeated around 40-50 times (dependent on a given value at startup) and have spacing as needed.

Once I have a template, I foresee calling it in a loop and setting the appropriate displayed text(Label_1, Label_2, etc) and connect statements where needed.

As I said, I don't know how to template parts of the UI so they can be placed in a kind of auto-generation.

I had thought of making one group, copying the xml, and somehow adding it but that doesn't seem to be a proper way. A little new to Qt.

This is roughly the layout I want to repeat. It has two labels, a lineedit, and one pushbutton. 
[image: Layout to be repeated]

Comment: Added another approach to my answer, and an example based on your added image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "good" way to do this in QtDesigner/QtCreator. At best you could copy/paste the set of controls 50 times and then in C++ code hide the ones you don't need. But I wouldn't recommend this.

Instead, just create the controls (labels/button/text box), and a layout to hold them, in C++ code, inside a loop which iterates however many times you need at runtime. Insert the controls layout into the tab widget page layout which you have set up in designer mode. It is not difficult, and will actually be more efficient than what QtDesigner produces since that tends to generate more code than you typically need in the first place.

As a starting point, you could look at the C++ code which is generated by the Qt [UI Compiler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) (UIC) tool for your current design (it takes the XML from designer and turns it into C++ code). You can find this in the build folder for your project, typically named something like `ui_ClassName.h`, probably in a `ui` subfolder of the build tree.

**UPDATE:**

Another, possibly better, way to do this is to create the "template" `QWidget` class/form, which is going to be used multiple times, as a separate object. The "template" design could be created/maintained using QtCreator/Designer (or just directly in C++). The (possible) advantage here is that as the app requirements evolve, the template widget can be expanded with additional functionality or even re-used in other parts of the UI.

For example, I'd assume the text editor and button in the given mockup image will actually need to do something (eg. edit data and submit it). So some basic functionality can be built into the "template" widget, for example to emit a signal with the text contents of the line editor when the button is pressed.

I put together a quick example. I'm creating the simple `MainWindow` in pure C++ to simplify/shorten the example code. The "template" I'm calling an `Editor`. The `Editor` class and UI form I initially created with the QtCreator wizard (New -> Qt Designer Form Class). I then added the label/control widgets in designer mode. And in C++, a `textEdited(const QString &text)` signal in the header, and in the `Editor()` constructor a lambda connection to emit that signal when the button is pressed.

The `Editor` class code is straight out of the QtCreator wizard except for two edits I'm highlighting below. The designer form has two relevant controls: a `QLineEdit` (`lineEdit`) and a `QPushButton` (`pushButton`). I'll link to the full files below.

Editor.h

```cpp
  // in the Editor class declarations:
  signals:
    void textEdited(const QString &text) const;
```

Editor.cpp

```cpp
  // in the constructor, after ui->setupUi(this);
  connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]() {
    emit textEdited(ui->lineEdit->text());
  });
```

Test harness, including `MainWindow` subclass and `main()`

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include "Editor.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    MainWindow() : QMainWindow()
    {
      // set up a tab widget as the window central widget
      QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget(this);
      setCentralWidget(tabWidget);
      // the first/only page will contain all the editors in a vertical layout
      QWidget *editorsPage = new QWidget(this);
      editorsPage->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
      // add the editors container page to tab widget
      tabWidget->addTab(editorsPage, tr("Editors page"));

      // Now create a number of editor widgets using our Editor class "template"

      int layoutItems = 5;  // number of editors needed, could be dynamic
      for (int i=0; i < layoutItems; ++i) {
        // Create an Editor instance with the tab page as parent
        Editor *editor = new Editor(editorsPage);
        // Add the editor widget to the tab page layout
        editorsPage->layout()->addWidget(editor);

        // A simple connection with the editor signal, as way of example.
        connect(editor, &Editor::textEdited, this, [this](const QString &text) {
          // just show a message box with the editor text
          QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Text Edited"), text, QMessageBox::Ok);
        });
      }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

[image]

---

Links The full `Editor` code:
[Editor.h](http://max.wdg.us/SO/60086935/Editor.h)
[Editor.cpp](http://max.wdg.us/SO/60086935/Editor.cpp)
[Editor.ui](http://max.wdg.us/SO/60086935/Editor.ui.txt)

Comment: I tried it the hard way of doing what is in mainwindow_ui.h and that is not a happy friendly method. This is much simpler, I'll be testing it soon.

Comment: How can I extend it horizontally? I tried switching to a gridlayout, but it only centered it. Addwidget() using the gridlayout did not present the manual placement functions.

Comment: Fixed by making the layout into a variable before adding it to the parent widget.

Comment: @ConductedForce Right, for a grid you usually need to specify a row and column to place a widget into. Or of course a `QHboxLayout` could be used instead of the `QVBoxLayout` in the example (in which case just `addWidget()` still works). If you know the `layout()` is a `QGridLayout` you could also cast it: `QGridLayout *gl = qobject_cast<QGridLayout*>(editorsPage->layout()); if (gl) ...`.  Anyway, glad this helped!

Answer (score 1):

The XML in Qt Creator is for [UIC](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) in QMake to generator code for you.
For example, QMake translates your `mainwindow.ui` to `ui_mainwindow.h`, and within you will find `void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)` with the actual code that creates and places the widgets.

Look at this code, the docs, and create and place the widgets yourself by code.

For example, adding 5 checkboxes to a groupbox by code:

```
QVBoxLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
ui->groupBox_4->setLayout(l);
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    QCheckBox *c = new QCheckBox(this);
    l->addWidget(c);
}
```

Comment: `qmake` is not the generator, the tool is called [uic](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html). Works with CMake, any other build system, or can be run manually from a command line.